# Can I force a user to sign-in on iOS for a Consumable in-app product?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an existing app in the iOS app-store and am offering the ability for users to buy Albums of pictures as consumable in-app products. Can I force a user to sign in to be able to buy them? These albums all have the same price of $1.99 but there can be 20 different ones that a user can buy, hence why I believe they should be consumable.

I had previously added a feature to upgrade an account from Basic to Paid and was forcing users to signup or login, but the app was rejected. This was for a non-consumable in-app products though - so I am hopeful that for consumable in-app products it is different.

I have tried doing some research and looking at the official Apple documentation, but nothing was 100% clear.

Comment: I don't believe that you can require the user to log in; You can provide details about the benefits that they will obtain (The ability to access pictures on other devices or if they erase their current device and re-install the app) but if they choose not to create an account that is their choice.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

### Section 5.1.1

Actually, IANAL but I think Apple explicitly forbids what you would like to do:

> Account Sign-In: If your app doesn’t include significant account-based
>   features, let people use it without a log-in. Apps may not require
>   users to enter personal information to function, except when directly
>   relevant to the core functionality of the app or required by law. If
>   your core app functionality is not related to a specific social
>   network (e.g. Facebook, WeChat, Weibo, Twitter, etc.), **you must
>   provide access without a login** or via another mechanism.